# stm32f207 program doesn't work without entering debug

Tags: debugging, ethernet, stm32

There is a microcontroller sends UDP packets over ethernet. Problem is - after restarting a power MC sends nothing over ethernet if i don't enter into debug mode.

I use IAR 6.6 and everything works fine if i enter into debug mode also WITHOUT downloading the code. I added a delay for few seconds but it doesn't work without debug.

What can be the problem?

Comment: May be your boot configuration is not set to main flash?

Comment: Is the CPU running at all? Try to add a blinking LED / IO pin. Maybe the MCU runs into an exception? Do you have a serial debug port, if yes: try to add debug output to verify that is boots up okey. If only the ethernet is the problem, issue a MAC reset, and make sure that the MAC and the PHY is configured to the same link speed (they can easy go out of sync if the init code is not forcing this)